# AttributeError When Retrieving Object in Django

Tags: python, django

For every movie download on my webapp, I want to inform the uploader through mail that his movie have been downloaded. I wrote the below code, it seems I'm finding it hard to get the query right.

```
  AttributeError at /download/

 'unicode' object has no attribute 'email'
```

Models:

```
class Emovie(models.Model):
    User=models.ForeignKey(User)
    movie_file=models.FileField(upload_to='miiv')
    movie_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField()   #email of the uploader
    #other fields follows
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def document_view(request, emovie_id, urlhash):
    document=Emovie.objects.get(id=emovie_id, urlhash=urlhash)
    downstats=Emovie.objects.filter(id=emovie_id, urlhash=urlhash).update(download_count=F('download_count')+1)
    #where email notification starts
    notify=Emovie.objects.filter(id=emovie_id.email)
    send_mail('Your file has just been downloaded','this works','test@test.com',[notify])
    response = HttpResponse()
    response["Content-Disposition"]= "attachment; filename={0}".format(document.pretty_name)
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = "/protected_files/{0}".format(document.up_stuff)
    return response
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens here: `Emovie.objects.filter(id=emovie_id.email)`.

`emovie_id` is a unicode (string) object which means you can't do `.email` on it. Given that you want to filter on `id=` I think you meant to write: `Emovie.objects.get(id=int(emovie_id))`.

Comment: ..and `[notify.email]` instead `[notify]` in the next line.

Comment: I'm getting this error. 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'email'. Any idea?

Comment: I've fixed it. It Should be get() not filter(), Like Emovie.objects.get(id=int(emovie_id))

Comment: I have a question, after making the changes, django do send more than one mail to the uploader, when a user download the movie once. why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
notify=Emovie.objects.get(id=emovie_id).email
```

with

```
notify=Emovie.objects.filter(id=emovie_id.email)
```

It will work fine...

Comment: emovie_id will be unique for each emovie.. So Above query will work in all condition.

Comment: I did what you said before asking for help on SO. It's not working.